# why postify works and stringify doesn't?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

In server side I have following class

```
public class EditorContext
{       
    public Module Module { get; set; }     
    public Holder Holder { get; set; }
}   
public class Module
{
    public string CodeName { get; set; }        
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
public class Holder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int Type { get; set; }
}

public class EditorController : Controller
{                
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult AddModule(EditorContext context)
    {            
        return Json(new { });
    }        
}
```

From the client I send request like this

```
var data =
{
     Module:
     {
          CodeName: 1,
          Content: 2
     },
     Holder:
     {
          Type: 3,
          Id: 4
     }
};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Editor/AddModule',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: false,
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              throw new Error();
        }
});
```

1 - Fiddler shows that he sent **{"Module":{"CodeName":1,"Content":2},"Holder":{"Type":3,"Id":4}}**, but in server **Request.Form = %7b%22Module%22%3a%7b%22CodeName%22%3a1%2c%22Content%22%3a2%7d%2c%22Holder%22%3a%7b%22Type%22%3a3%2c%22Id%22%3a4%7d%7d**, WHY?

2 - If instead of "JSON.stringify(data)" I use "postify" like in [here](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/), so EditorController.AddModule gets already filled EditorContext. This **postify** change the data to "Model.CodeName=1&Model.Content=2&Holder.Type=3&Holder.Id=4". So, why in this way EditorContext is filled automatically by default binder and in (1) it doesn't?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the binder that your data is JSON, otherwise it has no idea it should be parsing it as such. Add the correct content type header to your request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Editor/AddModule',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              throw new Error();
        }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding **contentType: "application/json"**, but it didn't helped. The **EditorContext.Holder and EditorContext.Module** are null